# Admob React Native google mobile ads How can I add InterstitialAd when user go back from a particular page or exit a page

Tags: react-native, admob, react-navigation, google-ads-api

React native has its own default back button.

How can I add InterstitialAd in React Native, when I press React native back button from a page or if I exit the page(Not exiting the App) by pressing the Home button in Bottom Tabs Navigator bar.

I have added my Home button in Tabbar. so that a user directly clicks Home button from a particular page.

*This is the page where I have added InterstitialAd*

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Button, Text, ScrollView, } from 'react-native';
import { AppOpenAd, InterstitialAd, RewardedAd, BannerAd, TestIds, AdEventType } from 'react-native-google-mobile-ads';
const TestAds = ({ navigation }) => {
useEffect(() => {
        let interstitial = InterstitialAd.createForAdRequest(TestIds.INTERSTITIAL, {
            requestNonPersonalizedAdsOnly: true,
            keywords: ['fashion', 'clothing'],
        });
        interstitial.addAdEventListener(AdEventType.LOADED, () => {
            interstitial.show();
        });
        interstitial.load();
        return () => {
            interstitialListener = null;
        };
    }, []);
return (
        <ScrollView>
            <View>
                <View style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
                    <Text>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                        Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
</Text>
                </View>

            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    )
}
export default TestAds
```

*My App.js file*

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import Contact from './Contact';
import Test from './Test';
import TestAds from './TestAds';
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const HomeTabs = ({ navigation }) =>{
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Contact" component={Contact} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Test" component={Test} />
     </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
export default function App () {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeTabs} />
        <Tab.Screen name="TestAds" component={TestAds} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```